ProviderNotFoundException in the main.dart, how to fix it?
I encountered a ProviderNotFoundException in my Flutter application. This error occurred when I tried to access a ProfileProvider within the TapsHomePage widget, indicating that the ProfileProvider couldn't be found in the current context.
Can someone help me please? Here is the code of the main.dart and the TapsHomePage:
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final notificationService = NotificationService();
  await notificationService.initialize();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ProfileProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ThemeProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ChallengeProvider()),
        Provider<MockAuthModel>(create: (_) => MockAuthModel()),
        Provider<MockProfileModel>(create: (_) => MockProfileModel()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );

  notificationService.scheduleDailyNotification();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Log di debug per verificare che il provider ThemeProvider sia disponibile
    final themeProviderAvailable = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false) != null;
    print('Debug: ThemeProvider is available: $themeProviderAvailable');

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TOO-Taps',
      theme: context.watch<ThemeProvider>().currentTheme,
      home: const AuthWrapper(),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name == null) return null;

        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            if (settings.name == '/signup') return const SignUpPage();
            if (settings.name == '/login') return const LoginPage();
            return AuthCheck(
              builder: (context, userID) {
                return _buildPageForRoute(context, settings.name!, userID);
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPageForRoute(BuildContext context, String name, String userID) {
    // Log di debug per verificare che il ProfileProvider sia disponibile quando si costruisce la pagina
    final profileProviderAvailable = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context, listen: false) != null;
    print('Debug: ProfileProvider is available in _buildPageForRoute: $profileProviderAvailable');

    switch (name) {
      case '/taps_home':
        return TapsHomePage(userID: userID);
      case '/scrolling':
        return ScrollingPage(userID: userID);
      case '/pod':
        return const PodPage();
      case '/profilo':
        return ProfilePage(userID: userID);
      case '/challenge':
        return ChallengePage(userID: userID);
      default:
        return const LoginPage();
    }
  }
}

class AuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthWrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Log di debug per verificare che il ProfileProvider sia disponibile nel contesto di AuthWrapper
    final profileProviderAvailable = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context, listen: false) != null;
    print('Debug: ProfileProvider is available in AuthWrapper: $profileProviderAvailable');

    return AuthCheck(
      builder: (context, userID) {
        return const HomePage(); // Modifica questa parte in base al tuo flusso di navigazione
      },
    );
  }
}

class AuthCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, String) builder;

  const AuthCheck({super.key, required this.builder});

  @override
  State<AuthCheck> createState() => _AuthCheckState();
}

class _AuthCheckState extends State<AuthCheck> {
  final Logger _logger = Logger();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeProfile();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeProfile() async {
    // Log di debug per verificare che il ProfileProvider sia disponibile durante l'inizializzazione del profilo
    final profileProviderExists = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context, listen: false) != null;
    _logger.i('Debug: ProfileProvider is available in _initializeProfile: $profileProviderExists');

    if (profileProviderExists) {
      final profileProvider = context.read<ProfileProvider>();
      final mockAuth = context.read<MockAuthModel>();

      // Caricamento del profilo con un ritardo per garantire che il provider sia pronto
      await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
      profileProvider.setMockProfile(mockAuth.uid);
      _logger.i('Profile set for mock user: ${mockAuth.uid}');
    } else {
      _logger.e('ProfileProvider is not available in _initializeProfile');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Log di debug per verificare che il MockAuthModel sia disponibile
    final mockAuthExists = Provider.of<MockAuthModel>(context, listen: false) != null;
    _logger.i('Debug: MockAuthModel is available in AuthCheck build: $mockAuthExists');

    final mockAuth = context.watch<MockAuthModel>();
    _logger.i('AuthCheck: user is $mockAuth');

    return widget.builder(context, mockAuth.uid);
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = context.watch<ThemeProvider>();

    // Log di debug per verificare che il ProfileProvider sia disponibile nella HomePage
    final profileProviderAvailable = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context, listen: false) != null;
    print('Debug: ProfileProvider is available in HomePage: $profileProviderAvailable');

    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/taps_home');
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: themeProvider.boxDecoration,
          child: const Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

TapsHomePage:
class TapsHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userID;

  const TapsHomePage({super.key, required this.userID});

  @override
  TapsHomePageState createState() => TapsHomePageState();
}

class TapsHomePageState extends State<TapsHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  bool _isWelcomeMessageShown = false;
  final Logger _logger = Logger(); // Istanzia Logger

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
      vsync: this,
    )..repeat(reverse: true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _showWelcomeSnackbar(String userName) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Welcome, $userName'),
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _logger.i('TapsHomePage: Building with userID ${widget.userID}');

    // Verifica che il ProfileProvider sia disponibile nel contesto
    final profileProviderAvailable = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context, listen: false) != null;
    _logger.i('Debug: ProfileProvider is available in TapsHomePage: $profileProviderAvailable');

    if (!profileProviderAvailable) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('ProfileProvider not found in context.'),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: true);
        final profileProvider = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context, listen: true);
        final mockProfile = Provider.of<MockProfileModel>(context, listen: false);

        _logger.i('TapsHomePage: profileProvider is $profileProvider');

        final profile = profileProvider.profile ?? mockProfile; // Utilizza il profilo mock se necessario

        if (profile == null) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        if (!_isWelcomeMessageShown) {
          _isWelcomeMessageShown = true;
          _showWelcomeSnackbar(profile.displayName);
        }

        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (mounted) {
              profileProvider.incrementTouches();
              profileProvider.incrementScrolls();
            }
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0,
              title: const Text(
                'Custom Page',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                const ProfileButton(),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Logica mock per il logout se necessario
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Container(
              decoration: themeProvider.boxDecoration,
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Welcome, ${profile.displayName}',
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Touches: ${profile.touches}',
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 80),
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.accessibility_new, color: Colors.white),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: const NavigationHome(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


I added debug logs to check if the ProfileProvider and other providers (like MockAuthModel) were available in the context at various points in the application.
The logs confirmed that the ProfileProvider and MockAuthModel were indeed available in the contexts where I expected them to be, but the ProviderNotFoundException persisted.
I examined the usage of the Builder widget, particularly in the TapsHomePage widget. The Builder was being used to rebuild parts of the UI based on the current context, which could potentially cause issues if the context didn’t have access to the ProfileProvider.
I considered whether the Builder might be positioned in a context that didn’t include the ProfileProvider or if the ProfileProvider was being accessed before it was properly initialized.
I carefully reviewed the TapsHomePage widget, where the error was occurring. I checked if the widget was being built in a context that includes the MultiProvider containing the ProfileProvider.
I confirmed that TapsHomePage was correctly accessing ProfileProvider, but the error still suggested that there might be a context issue when Builder was being used.
